# Define list of elements in a GitHub Action variable

Tags: github, github-actions

Since a few weeks GitHub introduced [required workflows and configuration variables](https://github.blog/2023-01-10-introducing-required-workflows-and-configuration-variables-to-github-actions/).

Now I want to define a global GitHub Actions workflow that uses a variable that is not a simple string of text, but a list of elements.

`TEST_OS_VERSION = '"ubuntu", "ubuntu-20.04"'`

```yaml
        os: [${{ vars.TEST_OS_VERSIONS }}]
```

Seems that GitHub does not like that :-/

I already tried `TEST_OS_VERSION = '["ubuntu", "ubuntu-20.04"]'`  and `os: ${{vars.TEST_OS_VERSIONS }}` but again GitHub does not like it either.

Any idea on how to store in a variable a list of elements to be used in GitHub?

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentions @jonrsharpe [fromJSON](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#fromjson) is the solution:

Variable: `["ubuntu", "ubuntu-20.04"]`

yaml: `os: ${{ fromJSON(vars.TEST_OS_VERSIONS) }}`